# Java Sha1 in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, sha1, sinch

How to get the this Java SHA1 Result in PHP ?

```
    // Generating the Signature - Java
// import java.security.MessageDigest;
// import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String userId; 
String applicationKey; // E.g. "196087a1-e815-4bc4-8984-60d8d8a43f1d";
String applicationSecret; // E.g. "oYdgGRXoxEuJhGDY2KQ/HQ==";
long sequence; // fetch and increment last used sequence

String toSign = userId + applicationKey + sequence + applicationSecret;

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String signature = Base64.encodeBase64String(hash).trim();
```

I need the UTF-8 Sha1 On PHP, thank you

These code output different result than java utf-8 sha-1:

1:

```
$toSign_base64 = trim(base64_encode($toSign));
$toSign_digest = trim(hash_hmac('sha1', base64_decode($toSign_base64), "", true));
$signature = trim(base64_encode($toSign_digest));
```

2:

```
$signature = trim(sha1($toSign));
```

3:

```
$signature = trim(base64_encode(sha1($toSign)));
```

Result:

```
"raw": "849165ca-7af7-4951-6969-e19fc9f50b66",
"java_utf8_sha1": "1kBtMaSGLLiUfoSh9qJaxQGZTiQ=",
"code_1": "07PGV/+gMgCylXyA2qPJ92y1eSo=",
"code_2": "d6406d31a4862cb8947e84a1f6a25ac501994e24",
"code_3": "ZDY0MDZkMzFhNDg2MmNiODk0N2U4NGExZjZhMjVhYzUwMTk5NGUyNA=="
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: What's wrong with just using sha1() (other than SHA-1 no longer being considered a secure hash, of course)?

Comment: I use it for Sinch's Backend Auth, and it use Java UTF-8 SHA-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am 90% sure the php function sha1(); does it with utf8 encoding, 
Output as raw, then base64_encode it, so

```
<?php  base64_encode( sha1("849165ca-7af7-4951-6969-e19fc9f50b66", true) ); ?>
```

and see if it gives you the same as java ( I do not know java, only php )

Comment: it didn't work like the Java UTF 8 SHA-1, I've updated the first post about the results.

Comment: You need to output as raw then base64_encode it to get the same as java, I edited my ansewer with the updated code

Comment: It works, i didn't realize the sha1 have raw output, lol. Thank you very much sir.