# PHP implementation of JAVA's StandardStringDigester

Tags: java, php, encryption, sha1

I am trying to implement Java's StandardStringDigester digest function in PHP to digest a string with the SHA-1 algorithm. I do not have experience with encryption, so I have tried a few things without understanding them. The Working Java example is following:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Main
{

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    String x = "XUXoV2VYc7zYJ8UN";
    int n = 854;
    StandardStringDigester clientsd = new StandardStringDigester ();
      clientsd.setIterations (n - 1);
      clientsd.setAlgorithm ("SHA-1");
      clientsd.setSaltSizeBytes (0);    //no salt
    String clientDigest = clientsd.digest (x);
    String URLclientDigest = "a";
    try {
         URLclientDigest = URLEncoder.encode (clientDigest, "UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex){
                            System.out.println("Encoding not supported");
                            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
      System.out.println (URLclientDigest);
  }
}
```

In PHP I tried few things:

```
$n = 854;
$x = 'XUXoV2VYc7zYJ8UN';

return hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $x, null, $n);
```

I also tried the above code with `$n -1`.
In above examples `x` is the message and `n` is the iterations.
I am not really sure what I am doing here. Perhaps there is a PHP library someone can point me to or any direcction will be appreciated.

Comment: check [sha1 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659283/java-sha1-in-php) and this [library](https://github.com/kevwis/phpsypt/blob/master/Standard/Byte/Digester.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`StandardStringDigester`](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.3/org/jasypt/digest/StandardStringDigester.html) (which is part of the [*Jasypt*](http://www.jasypt.org/) library), the hash is generated as follows:

> The steps taken for creating digests are:
>
> 1. The String message is converted to a byte array
> 2. A salt of the specified size is generated (see SaltGenerator).
> 3. The salt bytes are added to the message.
> 4. The hash function is applied to the salt and message altogether, and then to the results of the function itself, as many times as
>    specified (iterations).
> 5. If specified by the salt generator (see SaltGenerator.includePlainSaltInEncryptionResults()), the undigested
>    salt and the final result of the hash function are concatenated and
>    returned as a result.
> 6. The result of the concatenation is encoded in BASE64 or HEXADECIMAL and returned as an ASCII String.

Since no salt is used in your case, a possible PHP implementation is:

```
$n = 854;
$x = 'XUXoV2VYc7zYJ8UN';

$hash = $x;
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $n - 1; $counter++){
    $hash = hash('sha1', $hash, true);
}

print(base64_encode($hash)); // QGFgek+pfZ6nMk8Jn3stOe5KeEY=
```

with the result `QGFgek+pfZ6nMk8Jn3stOe5KeEY=` analogous to the Java code (before the URL encoding).

Note: If a salt is used in the Java code (e.g. with `ByteArrayFixedSaltGenerator`), the salt in the PHP code must be concatenated with the message before the loop: `$hash = $salt . $x;` (instead of `$hash = $x;`).